# Virtual keyboard using UHID

Tags: keyboard, c, hid

I am trying to achieve what the QMK firmware does for keyboards but using software. So, I would like to turn off keys, substitute some keys for others, layers and etc.

The first thing that appeared for me when searching was [this example](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/uhid/uhid-example.c). The problem is, running the test it only works when the terminal that is executing the binary has focus, and I would like to overpass the windowing system.

Also the code presents this array that I don't have any idea how to fill.

```C
static unsigned char rdesc[] = {
    0x05, 0x01, /* USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop) */
    0x09, 0x02, /* USAGE (Mouse) */
    0xa1, 0x01, /* COLLECTION (Application) */
    0x09, 0x01,     /* USAGE (Pointer) */
    0xa1, 0x00,     /* COLLECTION (Physical) */
    0x85, 0x01,         /* REPORT_ID (1) */
    0x05, 0x09,         /* USAGE_PAGE (Button) */
    0x19, 0x01,         /* USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1) */
    0x29, 0x03,         /* USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 3) */
    0x15, 0x00,         /* LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0) */
    0x25, 0x01,         /* LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1) */
    0x95, 0x03,         /* REPORT_COUNT (3) */
    0x75, 0x01,         /* REPORT_SIZE (1) */
    0x81, 0x02,         /* INPUT (Data,Var,Abs) */
    0x95, 0x01,         /* REPORT_COUNT (1) */
    0x75, 0x05,         /* REPORT_SIZE (5) */
    0x81, 0x01,         /* INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs) */
    0x05, 0x01,         /* USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop) */
    0x09, 0x30,         /* USAGE (X) */
    0x09, 0x31,         /* USAGE (Y) */
    0x09, 0x38,         /* USAGE (WHEEL) */
    0x15, 0x81,         /* LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127) */
    0x25, 0x7f,         /* LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127) */
    0x75, 0x08,         /* REPORT_SIZE (8) */
    0x95, 0x03,         /* REPORT_COUNT (3) */
    0x81, 0x06,         /* INPUT (Data,Var,Rel) */
    0xc0,           /* END_COLLECTION */
    0xc0,       /* END_COLLECTION */
    0x05, 0x01, /* USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop) */
    0x09, 0x06, /* USAGE (Keyboard) */
    0xa1, 0x01, /* COLLECTION (Application) */
    0x85, 0x02,     /* REPORT_ID (2) */
    0x05, 0x08,     /* USAGE_PAGE (Led) */
    0x19, 0x01,     /* USAGE_MINIMUM (1) */
    0x29, 0x03,     /* USAGE_MAXIMUM (3) */
    0x15, 0x00,     /* LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0) */
    0x25, 0x01,     /* LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1) */
    0x95, 0x03,     /* REPORT_COUNT (3) */
    0x75, 0x01,     /* REPORT_SIZE (1) */
    0x91, 0x02,     /* Output (Data,Var,Abs) */
    0x95, 0x01,     /* REPORT_COUNT (1) */
    0x75, 0x05,     /* REPORT_SIZE (5) */
    0x91, 0x01,     /* Output (Cnst,Var,Abs) */
    0xc0,       /* END_COLLECTION */
};
```

I could not find any more documentation on the matter. At this time, I am not even sure if it is possible to do what I want. I have seen things like [KMonad](https://github.com/kmonad/kmonad) that I could not get to work.

At the end, these are my questions:

- How to fill the `rdesc` array to keyboards?
- How to overpass the windowing system?
- Where can I find documentation about UHID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was trying to solve this myself, and kept running across this post. I think I found it, the rdisc variable here is the [HID Report Descriptor](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/hid/hidintro.html).
That kernel doc page states:

> The format of HID report descriptors is described by two documents, available from the USB Implementers Forum HID web page...

and then the kernel doc links specifically to [the HID USB Device Class Definition](https://www.usb.org/document-library/device-class-definition-hid-111) and to [the HID Usage Tables](https://usb.org/document-library/hid-usage-tables-14).

That should take care of your first question. For your third question there's [this documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/hid/uhid.html), which is sparse, because UHID is basically just the glue for a userspace HID driver, and you'll get more out of the regular HID documentation. Sorry, I don't really know enough to provide an answer to your second question.